# Как запустить таймер, а потом отключить его?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть событие `<button onclick='start()'>Старт</button>` и `<button onclick='stop()'>Стоп</button>`

Как при нажатии на `"Старт"` запустить таймер `setInterval(5000)`, а при нажатии на `"Стоп"` остановить его?

Написал функцию, но она не очищает таймер, а только клонирует его

```
var sender = (function () {
    return function (callback, ms, stop) {
        clearInterval(time);
        var time = setInterval(callback, ms);
        if (stop) {
            clearInterval(time);
        }

    }

})();

function start () {
 sender (function () {
  alert ('start');
 }, 5000);

   function stop () {
 sender (function () {
  alert ('stop');
 }, 5000, 1);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Дайте переменной stop значение по умолчанию, и функцию clearInterval поднимите вверх, дело в том что вы всегда запускаете setInterval, даже если отправили запрос на остановку, а потом только останавливаете\

Comment: Или clearInterval(time); добавьте в функцию stop(), если переменная time там в области видимости, конечно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ сам. Для тех кому также придется с этим столкнуться есть готовое решение:

```
var sender = function () {
        console.log('YES');
};
var startSender;
function start () {
   startSender = setInterval (startSender, 5000);
 }

function stop () {
   cleanInterval (startSender);
 }
```

Пользуйтесь